# RewriteCond with negative conditions rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite all URL that was indexed in Google `example.com/zzz.php` to `example.com/zzz/` and it works with the following code (in `.htaccess`):

```
# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I have a new problem with this, it's broken my ajax and some pages of my wp-admin because phpless.

[image]

Someone have a idea of RewriteCond with negative conditions for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create some exceptions (as needed). For example:

```
# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the regex. So the above will exclude requests that start with `/wp-admin/`.

> `example.com/zzz.php` to `example.com/zzz/`

Note that the redirect above would redirect to `example.com/zzz` - no trailing slash.